# I am trying to find Duplicate in access query without deleting

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to buid an expressions in access. I need to have some sort of flag if item code and InvoiceNo are duplicate. I am hoping the column to indicate -1.

```
ItemCode    UnitPrice   InvoiceNo
R50         18.60       0446394
R50         18.60       0446395
R64         20.60       0444965
R64         20.60       0444965
R64         22.60       0446394
R64         22.60       0446394
G32         24.60       0445689
```

Can you please assist?
Here is the sql I used to get those results.

SELECT [Amerinet sales].[sales person], [Amerinet sales].ShipToName, [Amerinet sales].ShipToAddress1, [Amerinet sales].ShipToAddress2, [Amerinet sales].ShipToAddress3, [Amerinet sales].ShipToCity, [Amerinet sales].ShipToState, [Amerinet sales].ShipToZipCode, [Amerinet sales].ItemCode, [Amerinet sales].UnitPrice, [Amerinet sales].QuantityShipped, [Amerinet sales].ExtensionAmt, [Amerinet sales].InvoiceDate, [Amerinet sales].InvoiceNo, [Amerinet sales].Totals, [Amerinet sales].BillToName, [Amerinet sales].BillToAddress1, [Amerinet sales].BillToAddress2, [Amerinet sales].BillToAddress3, [Amerinet sales].BillToCity, [Amerinet sales].BillToState, [Amerinet sales].BillToZipCode, [Amerinet Match].[sales person], [Amerinet Match].ShipToName, [Amerinet Match].ShipToAddress1, [Amerinet Match].ShipToAddress2, [Amerinet Match].ShipToAddress3, [Amerinet Match].ShipToCity, [Amerinet Match].ShipToState, [Amerinet Match].ShipToZipCode, [Amerinet Match].ItemCode, [Amerinet Match].UnitPrice, [Amerinet Match].QuantityShipped, [Amerinet Match].ExtensionAmt, [Amerinet Match].InvoiceDate, [Amerinet Match].InvoiceNo, [Amerinet Match].Totals, [Amerinet Match].BillToName, [Amerinet Match].BillToAddress1, [Amerinet Match].BillToAddress2, [Amerinet Match].BillToAddress3, [Amerinet Match].BillToCity, [Amerinet Match].BillToState, [Amerinet Match].BillToZipCode, [Amerinet Match].[GPO ID], [Amerinet Match].GLN, [Amerinet Match].Field3, [Amerinet Match].[DEA #], [Amerinet Match].[Name 1], [Amerinet Match].[Address 1], [Amerinet Match].City, [Amerinet Match].[State/Province], [Amerinet Match].[Postal Code], [Amerinet Match].[Name 2], [Amerinet Match].[Address Type], [Amerinet Match].[Address 2], [Amerinet Match].[Address 3], [Amerinet Match].Country, [Amerinet Match].Phone, [Amerinet Match].Fax, [Amerinet Match].Field17, [Amerinet Match].Field18, [Amerinet Match].[Direct Parent GPO ID], [Amerinet Match].[Direct Parent Name 1], [Amerinet Match].[Top Parent GPO ID], [Amerinet Match].[Top Parent Name 1], [Amerinet Match].Field23, [Amerinet Match].Field24, [Amerinet Match].Field25, [Amerinet Match].[Class of Trade], [Amerinet Match].Field27, [Amerinet Match].Field28, [Amerinet Match].Field29, [Amerinet Match].Field30, [Amerinet Match].Field31, [Amerinet Match].Field32, [Amerinet Match].Field33, [Amerinet Match].Field34, [Amerinet Match].[Sub-Class], [Amerinet Match].Alliance, [Amerinet Match].IDN, [Amerinet Match].[Sole Source Mbr Y/N], [Amerinet Match].[# of Beds]
FROM [Amerinet sales] LEFT JOIN [Amerinet Match] ON ([Amerinet sales].ItemCode = [Amerinet Match].ItemCode) AND ([Amerinet sales].InvoiceNo = [Amerinet Match].InvoiceNo)
GROUP BY [Amerinet sales].[sales person], [Amerinet sales].ShipToName, [Amerinet sales].ShipToAddress1, [Amerinet sales].ShipToAddress2, [Amerinet sales].ShipToAddress3, [Amerinet sales].ShipToCity, [Amerinet sales].ShipToState, [Amerinet sales].ShipToZipCode, [Amerinet sales].ItemCode, [Amerinet sales].UnitPrice, [Amerinet sales].QuantityShipped, [Amerinet sales].ExtensionAmt, [Amerinet sales].InvoiceDate, [Amerinet sales].InvoiceNo, [Amerinet sales].Totals, [Amerinet sales].BillToName, [Amerinet sales].BillToAddress1, [Amerinet sales].BillToAddress2, [Amerinet sales].BillToAddress3, [Amerinet sales].BillToCity, [Amerinet sales].BillToState, [Amerinet sales].BillToZipCode, [Amerinet Match].[sales person], [Amerinet Match].ShipToName, [Amerinet Match].ShipToAddress1, [Amerinet Match].ShipToAddress2, [Amerinet Match].ShipToAddress3, [Amerinet Match].ShipToCity, [Amerinet Match].ShipToState, [Amerinet Match].ShipToZipCode, [Amerinet Match].ItemCode, [Amerinet Match].UnitPrice, [Amerinet Match].QuantityShipped, [Amerinet Match].ExtensionAmt, [Amerinet Match].InvoiceDate, [Amerinet Match].InvoiceNo, [Amerinet Match].Totals, [Amerinet Match].BillToName, [Amerinet Match].BillToAddress1, [Amerinet Match].BillToAddress2, [Amerinet Match].BillToAddress3, [Amerinet Match].BillToCity, [Amerinet Match].BillToState, [Amerinet Match].BillToZipCode, [Amerinet Match].[GPO ID], [Amerinet Match].GLN, [Amerinet Match].Field3, [Amerinet Match].[DEA #], [Amerinet Match].[Name 1], [Amerinet Match].[Address 1], [Amerinet Match].City, [Amerinet Match].[State/Province], [Amerinet Match].[Postal Code], [Amerinet Match].[Name 2], [Amerinet Match].[Address Type], [Amerinet Match].[Address 2], [Amerinet Match].[Address 3], [Amerinet Match].Country, [Amerinet Match].Phone, [Amerinet Match].Fax, [Amerinet Match].Field17, [Amerinet Match].Field18, [Amerinet Match].[Direct Parent GPO ID], [Amerinet Match].[Direct Parent Name 1], [Amerinet Match].[Top Parent GPO ID], [Amerinet Match].[Top Parent Name 1], [Amerinet Match].Field23, [Amerinet Match].Field24, [Amerinet Match].Field25, [Amerinet Match].[Class of Trade], [Amerinet Match].Field27, [Amerinet Match].Field28, [Amerinet Match].Field29, [Amerinet Match].Field30, [Amerinet Match].Field31, [Amerinet Match].Field32, [Amerinet Match].Field33, [Amerinet Match].Field34, [Amerinet Match].[Sub-Class], [Amerinet Match].Alliance, [Amerinet Match].IDN, [Amerinet Match].[Sole Source Mbr Y/N], [Amerinet Match].[# of Beds];

Comment: Better do a separate query in which you group by item code and invoice no and make a count(*) as an aggregation if you just need to find out if there are duplicates at all. [http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp]

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
select t.*,
       iif(cnt > 1, -1, 0) as HasDuplicate
from test as t inner join
      (select itemcode, invoiceno, count(*) as cnt
       from test as t
       group by itemcode, invoiceno
      ) as ii
      on ii.itemcode = t.itemcode and ii.invoiceno = t.invoiceno;
```

Comment: Did you replace `table` with your table name?

Comment: I did but I also forgot to mention that this is result to a query. I have included my query above. Can you help me add this to it?

Answer (score 0):

[Have you tried it with an inner join?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208854%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

**After adding a column called dupe I tested this query out with your data using MySQL. Should work for access.**

```
update test a
join (SELECT itemCode, invoiceNo
            from test t 
    GROUP BY itemCode, invoiceNo 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) x 
ON (a.itemCode = x.itemCode AND a.invoiceNo = x.invoiceNo)
SET dupe = "-1"
```

produces the following output

```
"itemCode"  "UnitPrice" "InvoiceNo" "dupe"
"R50"            "19"    "0446394"  "0"
"R50"            "19"    "0446395"  "0"
"R64"            "21"    "0444965"  "-1"
"R64"            "21"    "0444965"  "-1"
"R64"            "23"    "0446394"  "-1"
"R64"            "23"    "0446394"  "-1"
"G32"            "25"    "0445689"  "0"
```

Comment: I forgot to mentioned that this is result to a query. Here is the query sql I used to get the results(listed above). Can you let me know how to add it here?

Comment: If you want to add an indicator column you do this in separate query.  Then you can incorporate the isDupe column into your selection criteria for the above query as needed.  Otherwise, if you must do this as part of that giant query you can just add it to your FROM clause

Comment: Let me clarify my last comment.  If you want to add an indicator column you do this in separate update query.  Then you can incorporate the isDupe column into your selection criteria for subsequent queries as needed.  Otherwise, if you must do this as part of that giant query you can add the SELECT portion to your FROM clause by removing the UPDATE and SET clauses and correlating your query against the result set.